# in a controller in asp.net-mvc how can i get information about the users browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser

I am logging errors on my asp.net-mvc site and I wanted to see if there is anyway to detect the users browser info (name, version, etc) as it seems like people are getting issue but its because they are using very old browser.  This info would help me avoid debugging time if I know they are using a "Not supported" browser.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You may try the [Request.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.browser.aspx) property. It will contain pretty much everything you might need about the client browser (assuming it is sending the UserAgent header properly of course).

Comment: Seems Request.Browser.Browser is the one to check for browser names.

Answer (score 68):

You can get the supplied User Agent which gives browser information:

```
Request.UserAgent
```

There is a site which lists browser user agent strings: http://www.useragentstring.com

Other values you may be interested in.

```
Request.Browser.Platform
Request.Browser.Version
Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion
```