# How to load different views on different desktop browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I am creating ASP.Net mvc4 application..In this, I want to load different views for different browsers on desktop version..

In mvc4 we can load different views for desktop vs. mobile but here I want to load different views for desktop browsers and in same browser but different versions like

desktop chrome vs. desktop IE9
desktop IE8 vs. desktop IE9

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i don't think different `View` for each **desktop** browser is the way to go, the problems you're trying to address are probably `Css`/`JavaScript` issues and not related to the `View` which basically should contain content and not functionality / design.

However, you can leverage the new `DisplayModeProvider` mechanism (in MVC 4):

In your `Global.asax`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Internet Explorer 9 (view prefix will be "ie9")
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("ie9")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("MSIE 9.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });

        // Internet Explorer 8 (view prefix will be "ie8")
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("ie8")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("MSIE 8.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });

        // Internet Explorer 7 (view prefix will be "ie7")
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("ie7")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("MSIE 7.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });

        // Google Chrome (view prefix will be "chrome")
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("chrome")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("Chrome", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });

        // Mozilla Firefox (view prefix will be "firefox")
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("firefox")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("Firefox", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });
```

In your `Views` folder:

```
  /Views/[Controler]/[Action].ie9.cshtml
  /Views/[Controler]/[Action].ie8.cshtml
  /Views/[Controler]/[Action].ie7.cshtml
  /Views/[Controler]/[Action].chrome.cshtml
  /Views/[Controler]/[Action].firefox.cshtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309865/in-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-get-information-about-the-users-browser) help you?

Or you can use [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) plugin if you want to know browser in View

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks for your reply...I can do this manually but here I want to do this using MVC4 in-build functionality (DisplayModeProvider) that works to load different views for desktop and mobile..