# Can razor be used to detect if user is on windows?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to be able to check and see if  a user is on windows regardless of version, can this be done using Razor with out having to look at each individual version? Was also interested in knowing if you can use Razor to detect which browser the user is on as well.

Comment: You're looking for the [User agent of the browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I added some more context to the question, is it possible to detect if they are on any windows version? So that multiple if statements don't need to be made for each Windows version.

Comment: Yes, did you check the question I linked to? It is elementary code, in particular note that all the Windows versions in the answer to that question identifies themselves as different versions of "Windows NT".

Comment: Yes sorry, I was looking at the link from my phone and noticed some had NT while others didn't looking at it now on my monitor I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Request.Browser and Request.UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309865/in-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-get-information-about-the-users-browser) properties to get information about the client's platform and browser.

Comment: is it possible to check for all versions of windows in one if statement rather than having to look at each individual version?

Comment: you mean like this? `if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT") > 0)`